# type error when sprintf list into string with python2 on linux

Tags: python, printf

type error when sprintf  list into string with python2  on linux

```
x = [ 'aa', 'bbbb', 'ccccccc' ]
f = '%-10s%-10s%-10s'
s = f % x
```

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: Make a tuple from `x`: `f % tuple(x)`

Comment: @vaultah, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `%` operator requires that the right-hand operand has to be a `tuple` or a subclass of `tuple`if the format has multiple positional placeholders.

That is why you need to convert the arguments into a `tuple`:

```
>>> f % tuple(x)
'aa        bbbb      ccccccc   '
```

---

On the other hand, if you use a format string with a single right-hand value, you should be cautious as well, if you don't know the type of the value:

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 'The value is %s' % foo
'The value is [1, 2, 3]'
>>> foo = (1, 2, 3)
>>> 'The value is %s' % foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Thus if you do not know the type of the single argument, you should *always* wrap it into a 1-tuple:

```
>>> foo = (1, 2, 3)
>>> 'The value is %s' % (foo,)
'The value is (1, 2, 3)'
```

---

That is why **it is now better to use the new** [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) ([PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)) especially for complex strings, as it is more powerful, and less prone to errors:

```
>>> x = ['aa', 'bbbb', 'ccccccc']
>>> '{:10}{:10}{:10}'.format(*x)
'aa        bbbb      ccccccc   '
```